# When dragging and dropping ListViewItems from one ListView to another, is there a way to get which ListView the ListViewItem was dragged from?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

**EDIT:** I don't think I'm asking my question in the right way. I'm gonna go off and do more research on this but I'll leave this question up in case it works for somebody else.

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I'm working on a application that has two file browsers (one remote and one local) that allows the user to simply drag and drop files between the two.

In order to allow the user to drag files into listed folders, I needed to make the ListViewItem of the folder highlight to get the directory from it using `ListView.FocusedItem` and use `ListViewItem.Selected = true` to make it appear highlighted to the user however in order to ensure only one item is selected at a time on the side the user is dragging into, I had to call `ListView.SelectedItems.Clear()` when the DragOver event is called.

The consequence of this is that the DragOver event is called whenever ANYTHING is dragged over the control and thus, if a user selects multiple items to  transfer, as soon as they drag them, they are all cleared except for the item that the user actually dragged from, which brings me to my question - is there anyway to get which ListView a ListViewItem was dragged from during the DragOver event? I've checked the DragEventArgs on MSDN but nothing seems to fit my purpose.

Comment: Did you check the ListviewItem.ListView property ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In addition to @bkdev comment, in this case you've got the ListView Property, but when you need any extra property not implemented i found myself very useful the Tag property, where you can put any object (eg in this case the ListView name)

Comment: This works on most controls. I'm not sure about your case. `ListViewItem item = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem;`

Answer (score 1):

You are facing three challenges:

- Knowing where the data come from
- Dragging several items, or maybe prevent that?? (*)
- Not losing the selection when dragging

Let's start with the last one: Are you using **the right event**? Do not use the `MouseDown` event! `ListView` has an `ItemDrag` event that **avoids** the selection problems.

The other two are resolved by dragging an **array** of `ListViewItems`. Here is a working example to drag from `listView2` to `listView1`:

```
private void listView2_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    // stuff all seleted items into an array
    var Items = listView2.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToArray();
    DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, Items);
    data.SetData(Items);
    listView1.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Move);  // move or copy?
}

private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // if we receive an array of ListViewItems show we are ready to move (or copy?)
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem[]))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}


private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem[]));
    ListViewItem[] items = data as ListViewItem[];
    // data ok?
    if (items != null)
    // now loop over the array..
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in items)
        {
            // do stuff.. here we can check where we come from:
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi.Text + " coming from " + lvi.ListView.Name)
        }
}
```

Note that I take care to

- drag all selected items
- not just the text but the actual `ListViewItems`

Because we receive real `ListViewItems` in the `DragDrop` we can use their `ListView` property to test where they  come from:..

(*) Btw: If you only want one Item to be dragged, why not make the `ListView.MultiSelect = false` ??